# Powershell equivalent of `grep -r -l` (--files-with-matches)

Tags: powershell, grep

In Powershell, how do I list all files in a directory (recursively) that contain text that matches a given regex? The files in question contain really long lines of incomprehensible text, so I don't want to see the matching line -- just the filename.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `Select-String` to search for text inside files, and `Select-Object` to return specific properties for each match. Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.* | Select-String -Pattern "foobar" | Select-Object -Unique Path
```

Or a shorter version, using aliases:

```
dir -recurse *.* | sls -pattern "foobar" | select -unique path
```

If you want just the filenames, not full paths, replace `Path` with `Filename`.

---

#### Explanation:

1. [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)`-Recurse *.*` returns all files in the current directory and all its subdirectories.
2. [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)`-Pattern "foobar"` searches those files for the given pattern "foobar".
3. [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx)`-Unique Path` returns only the file path for each match; the `-Unique` parameter eliminates duplicates.

Comment: `select -Unique`... cool, learned something new. That works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Is *.* really needed? Get-ChildItem -Recurse works exactly the same I think.

Comment: or even more concisely, gci -r | sls "foobar" | select -unique path

Comment: If there's no matches PowerShell seems to "hang", it won't return. How does one know when the search is done if there are no matches?

Answer (score 2):

Note, that in powershell v1.0 and v2.0 you need to specify first position parameter (path) to work with `-Recursion`

[technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800(v=wps.620).aspx)

> -Recurse
>
> Gets the items in the specified locations and in all child items of
> the locations.
>
> In Windows PowerShell 2.0 and earlier versions of
> Windows PowerShell, the Recurse parameter works only when the value of
> the Path parameter is a container that has child items, such as
> C:\Windows or C:\Windows*, and not when it is an item does not have
> child items, such as C:\Windows*.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command inside the directory you would like to perform the "grep" and change `[SEARCH_PATTERN]` to match what you would like to match. It's recursive, searching through all files in the directory.

```
dir -Recurse | Select-String - pattern [SEARCH_PATTERN]
```

http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1205-how-to-use-powershell-to-recursively-search-for-text-within-files-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

[Select-String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) has a `-List` parameter for this purpose:

> Return only the first match in each input file.
>   By default, Select-String returns a MatchInfo object for each match found.

— [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html)

You can use it like this:

```
gci -Recurse | sls -List FOOBAR
```

Here's what some sample results look like (searching the Windows SDK for `ERROR_SUCCESS`):

```
shared\bthdef.h:576:#define BTH_ERROR(_btStatus)   ((_btStatus) != BTH_ERROR_SUCCESS)
shared\netioapi.h:2254:    ERROR_SUCCESS on success.  WIN32 error code on error.
shared\rpcnterr.h:34:#define RPC_S_OK                          ERROR_SUCCESS
shared\winerror.h:214:// MessageId: ERROR_SUCCESS
um\advpub.h:40://      ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED        Reboot required.
um\bluetoothapis.h:243://      ERROR_SUCCESS
um\ClusApi.h:571:_Success_(return == ERROR_SUCCESS)
um\dsparse.h:102:_Success_(return == ERROR_SUCCESS)
um\eapmethodpeerapis.h:228:// If the function succeeds, it returns ERROR_SUCCESS. Otherwise, it is
um\eappapis.h:56:// If the functions succeed, they return ERROR_SUCCESS. Otherwise, it is
um\MapiUnicodeHelp.h:583:                if ((hkeyPolicy && RegQueryValueExW(hkeyPolicy, szName, 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)
&dwLcid, &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS && dwType == REG_DWORD) ||
um\Mddefw.h:127:            routine will return ERROR_SUCCESS and the inherited data even if
um\Msi.h:1693:// Returns ERROR_SUCCESS if file is a package.
um\MsiQuery.h:192:// Returns ERROR_SUCCESS if successful, and the view handle is returned,
um\msports.h:46:    ERROR_SUCCESS if the dialog was shown
um\ncryptprotect.h:164:    ERROR_SUCCESS
um\NTMSAPI.h:1761:_Success_ (return == ERROR_SUCCESS)
um\oemupgex.h:108://  Returns:    ERROR_SUCCESS in case of success, win32 error otherwise
um\PatchWiz.h:90://                     ERROR_SUCCESS, plus ERROR_PCW_* that are listed in constants.h.
um\Pdh.h:415:_Success_(return == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

If you wanted to get back the actual `FileInfo` objects (instead of the relative Path and a single match result), you might use it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | where { Select-String -Path $_ -List -Pattern FOOBAR }
```

Comment: How can I get an output like the one you show, but that list all the lines (and not just one per file) that match the pattern

Comment: A way too elaborate formatted version: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.* | Select-String -List  "$args" | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize -Property Filename, @{Expression={$_.LineNumber}; Label="LN"; Width=3}, Line`.