# How do I "grep" output in Windows

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Every answer I've found to get a video's duration with ffmpeg contains `grep`, which `cmd` doesn't natively have.

I know there's a "Grep for windows" thing, but I'd rather use a function that comes with the command line.

So when I do `ffmpeg -i input` I get

```
Input #0, flv, from 'vid_test001.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Fri Sep 19 15:58:17
  Duration: 00:00:12.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 806 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: nellymoser, 22050 Hz, mono, flt
```

I'd like to to get the Duration from this, which is "00:00:12.44" in this case

Comment: Install Cygwin.

Comment: You can pipe command output in cmd just like you do in unix shell. And there are some commands like find, findstr that may mimick grep to some extent. Otherwise, get cygwin as @DanielRHicks suggested.

Comment: I'm looking for "a function that comes with the command line".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i "inputFile" 2>&1 | for /f "tokens=2 delims=, " %a in ('findstr /r /c:"^ *Duration:"') do echo %a
```

Execute `ffmpeg` on the input file, sending the output of stderr (where ffmpeg writes its information by default) to the standard output. Filter the list with `findstr` to retrieve the lines that begin with spaces followed by `Duration:`. For each line found, spaces and commas as considered as field delimiters and the second token in the line is requested, that is, the time after the `Duration:` label. This value is retrieved into the `for` replaceable parameter `%a` that is echoed to console.

To use from batch file, escape percent signs, replacing `%` with `%%`

Comment: I think you are missing a closing ' at: ('findstr /r /c:"^ *Duration:").  I think it should be ('findstr /r /c:"^ *Duration:"')

Comment: @cliffclof, of course you are right. Answer updated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using Powershell (comes standard in recent versions of Windows), you can make use of the `Select-String` command.

Here's a great post from another Superuser question - [link](https://superuser.com/a/742120/371394)

Basically, you can take the output of the command and pipe the results to select-string.